# How can run polip with supervisor?

Tags: supervisor, polipo

**Question:**

How I can run [`polipo`](https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/manual/) with `supervisorctl` command?

> I know I can run `polipo` with `systemctl`:

```
sudo systemctl start polipo.service
```

**But:**

I want to control it with **supervisor**

**Supervisor conf**

```
[program:api_my_project]
command=/home/my_project/.virtualenvs/my_project//bin/celery -A my_project worker -Q app_server_plus --loglevel=info --concurrency=2 -n my_project.%(process_num)02d
directory=/home/my_project/project_dir
user=proxy
numprocs=2
process_name=%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=INT
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/api/my_project.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/api/my_project.log
redirect_stderr=true
environment='something'
```